# Conda search - specify version and build string

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to specify a version number *and* build string using Conda:

```
# Specify the version number:
conda search "numpy==1.23.1"
```

Working OK

```
# Specify both version and build:
conda search "numpy==1.23.1==py39hc836922_0"
InvalidVersionSpec: Invalid version '1.23.1==py39hc836922_0': invalid character(s)
```

Is this possible using `Conda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with just one equal sign (`=`).

```
conda search "numpy=1.23.1=py39hc836922_0"
```